# Consequences of changing __type__

Tags: python, types, factory

I'm attempting to create what a believe (in my ignorance) is known as a class factory. Essentially, I've got a parent class that I'd like to take an `__init__` argument and become one of several child classes. I found an example of this recommended on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456672/class-factory-in-python), and it looks like this:

```
class Vehicle(object):
  def __init__(self, vtype):
    self.vtype = vtype
    if vtype=='c':
      self.__class__ = Car
    elif vtype == 't':
      self.__class__ = Truck
```

I've [heard](http://effbot.org/zone/python-objects.htm) that changing `__type__` can be dangerous. Are there any negative approaches to this approach? I'd use a function to dynamically create objects, but it wouldn't work with  the existing code I'm using. It expects a class where I plan to do the dynamic type change.

Thanks!

Comment: changing `__type__` is more than dangerous; it is crazy.  There are far better ways to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I think a class factory is defined as a callable that returns a class (not an instance):

```
def vehicle_factory(vtype):
    if vtype == 'c':
        return Car
    if vtype == 't':
        return Truck

VehicleClass = vehicle_factory(c)
vehicle_instance_1 = VehicleClass(*args, **kwargs)
VehicleClass = vehicle_factory(t)
vehicle_instance_2 = VehicleClass(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: "I think a class factory is defined as a callable that returns a class (not an instance)" why are you saying that? and why will i create a class that return class and after i should instancy them ?? i think you miss understand the name "class factory"

Comment: @singularity: You use a class factory when your class is not defined in a source file and you need to build the class on the fly, for example, when the class properties and methods are based on dynamic parameters stored in a database. I use this method to create django forms dynamically.

Comment: i don't understand why you are telling me that :) i think my comment was clear but i will repeat it, i was arguing about the definition that you give on a class factory (factory pattern) when you said that a class factory should return class and not instance because it's not; and i told you that you miss understood the name "class factory" to make it easier class factory is a "class  that implement the factory pattern" and not as you thought "a factory pattern that return class". hopefully this can clear things :)

Comment: @singularity: may be you are right and I misread http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Answer (score -1):

Don't do it this way. [Override `__new__()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900896/python-question-about-factory-functions/3900942#3900942) instead.

Comment: "Are there any negative approaches to this approach?"  Not really an answer.